# GET endpoint: Parsing parameters vs Adding a new endpoint

Tags: api-design

I have users and posts. Users can make posts. I am creating an endpoint for the posts. Does this make sense?

#### Posts

```
/posts - POST, create post
/posts?{uID} - GET, get posts for user
/posts?{pID} - GET, get post by id
/posts/{pID} - PUT, update post by id
```

Is this good design?  It seems that both GET requests are too similar. Should I create something more distinct like:

`/posts/users?{uID} - GET, get posts for user`

Cons of the first: Additional logic on the backend (if else logic, to see which parameter was passed)
Cons of the second: Additional endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I think most of your API design looks good, however you should change it slightly to follow the resource orientation suggested by the common API design guidelines:

```
/posts - POST, create post 
/posts?userId={uID} - GET, get posts for user 
/posts/{pID} - GET, get post by id 
/posts/{pID} - PUT, update post by id
```

If you would like to have a nested structure rather than a query string to get all posts of a user, I would suggest to do the following instead of `/posts/users?{uId}`:

```
/users/{uId}/posts - GET, get posts for user
```